# C# - boolean and if statement

Tags: c#

I'm currently writing code analysing images with the Google API Vision on Visual Studios.
But I have a problem that occures during my loop.
The analysis returns a list of annotation ( car, vehicle, land vehicle, etc.. ) and I wanted to filter it, with an "if", so i wrote this :

```
var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile("C:\\temp\\sequence\\1.jpg");
var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
var response = client.DetectLabels(image);
CropHintsAnnotation confidence = client.DetectCropHints(image);
bool empty = false;

foreach (var annotation in response)
{
    textBox1.Text += annotation.Description + "\r\n";
    textBox1.Text += "Score : " + annotation.Score + "\r\n";
    if (annotation.Description.Equals("vehicle"))
    {
        empty = false;
    }
    else
    {
        empty = true;
    }

}
textBox1.Text += "\r\nEmpty ?       " + empty + "\r\n\r\n";
```

So, if I wrote this well, it should say " Empty ? false ", because the analysis returns "vehicle" once.
I tried also to replace the :

```
annotation.Description.Equals("vehicle")
```

by

```
annotation.Description.Contains("vehicle") == true
```

but no way, it still says " Empty ? true ", as it should not.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for reading this, and for the help !

Comment: Would you mind taking a few minutes and improve the quality of your English please? I can't understand your question.

Comment: It will only ever return `true` if **the last annotation** equals "vehicle", because you overwrite the value of `empty` for each annotation. You should use `empty |= annotation.Description.Equast("vehicle")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here but assuming the `response` has more than one item the `empty` variable will only represent the value for the last one.

Reason is that for each iteration of the loop when it gets to the `if` statement it will enter it or the `else` and for sure will enter one of the two, so for each iteration the value of `empty` will be assigned and override the previous value

As for the code itself, it is neater to write it this way:

```
empty = !annotation.Description.Equals("vehicle");
```

What you should change is to move the line of the assigning into the loop:

```
foreach(/*...*/)
{
    /*...*/
    empty = !annotation.Description.Equals("vehicle");
    textBox1.Text += "\r\nEmpty ?       " + empty + "\r\n\r\n";
}
```

Comment: What I didn't understand was the fact that my empty value was only the last line. I should have seen this earlier.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Have your considered the case of the returned string? Try to ignore the case:

```
annotation.Description.Equals("vehicle", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Just a side note: The `Equals` function returns a `Boolean`, so you can remove the entire `if` statement and simplify your code to:

```
empty = !annotation.Description.Equals("vehicle", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Few possibilities :

1. Can you check the order of vehicle.It might also be that it actually does find a description of vehicle on say index 0, but index 1 is not vehicle and hence it overwrites the previous value. If this is the case, you might wish to break out of loop when your required condition is met.

   ```
   foreach (var annotation in response)
   {
       // not sure if you want this to 
       textBox1.Text += annotation.Description + "\r\n";
       textBox1.Text += "Score : " + annotation.Score + "\r\n";
       if (annotation.Description.Equals("vehicle",  
       StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
       {
           empty = false;
           textBox1.Text += "\r\nEmpty ?       " + empty + "\r\n\r\n";
           //possibly also break if you've achieved what you want.
           break;
       }
   }
   ```